# Splitting the group by on LINQ to Entities - composite query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

Let's say I have something like this:

```
... //Group By A
into anotherGroupByRangeVariable
...//Group By B
           Operation =  from item in anotherGroupByRangeVariable
                        group featureTitleGroupItem by
                        someKey into operationGrouping

                        select new Operation()
                        {
                            myProperty = operationGrouping.Key,
                            ...Other Attributes
                        });
```

Why I can't extract the second `group by` and use it on a method like this:

```
private static IQueryable<Operation> GroupByFeatureTitle(IGrouping<string, GroupByAItem> featureTitleGrouping)
        {
            return from item in anotherGroupByRangeVariable
                        group featureTitleGroupItem by
                        someKey into operationGrouping

                        select new Operation()
                        {
                            myProperty = operationGrouping.Key,
                            ...Other Attributes
                        }).AsQueryable();
        }
```

And make the call:

```
 ... //Group By A
    into anotherGroupByRangeVariable
    ...//Group By B
               Operation =  GroupByFeatureTitle(anotherGroupByRangeVariable)
```

When I try to execute it I get the error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Operation] GroupByFeatureTitle(System.Linq.IGrouping`2[NotificationChannelDao+ScopeChannelType])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

What is the best way to make a composite query with multiple inner group by's in LINQ to Entities to make the code more readable ?

Comment: Is the 2nd query running independently

Comment: No, the anotherGroupByRangeVariable is passed as a parameter to the second query.